# Post operation with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, post

I want to edit photo in my datatable with Jquery.For this,

```
<a href="ajax/edit_photo.php?id=<?=$row['ID']?>" class="edit ajax" id="">-->'Edit Photo Link'
```

**edit_photo.php:**

```
<div class="photoEdit">
    <form id="editphoto" action="1.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" method="post" class="stdform quickform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //My Forms...
    </form>

</div>
```

**My Jquery:**

```
jQuery('#editphoto').submit(function(){
            var formdata = jQuery(this).serialize();
            var url = jQuery(this).attr('action');
            jQuery.post(url, formdata, function(data){                          
            jQuery('.notifyMessage').addClass('notifySuccess');
                //otherwise
                //jQuery('.notifyMessage').addClass('notifyError');
                jQuery.fn.colorbox.resize();    
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**And My 1.php**

```
<? 
include("../../connection.php");
include("../../functions/upload.php");
?>
<?
$limit="1048576";
if(isset($_GET['kaydet'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $icerik=$_POST['icerik'];
    $picture=DoUpload("picture",$limit,$FileUploadPath);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_photo WHERE ID=$id");
    $picture2=mysql_result($result,0,"picture");
    if($picture=='')
    $picture=$picture2;
    if($picture!="")
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `tbl_photo` SET  `picture` =  '$picture',`icerik` =  '$icerik' WHERE `ID` =$id");
    }
}
?>
```

I coded something.But in my operation,Jquery doesn't work.So,does not to anything.

Comment: Did you invoke the jQuery library with a `<script>` tag?

Comment: yes i have script tags..

Comment: You used `POST` to make your request, but are looking for some of the arguments in `$_GET`.

Comment: Yes,'$_GET['id']' is id of photo in my datatable.

Comment: @MehmetEnder, but did you specifically get jQuery by doing something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="some/path/to/jQuery">`. ?

Comment: AFAIK you cant use `get` and `post` together, since your request was a `post` only `$_POST` values will be available

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload binary through jquery. You would have to use the iframe method, or use some jquery library. (This one is an easy one to try. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Plus you are mixing GET and POST in your PHP code. Since you are doing a POST request in jquery, you won't be able to get any variables in PHP using $_GET. They should all be replaced with $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

for image uploads or other binary data use a hidden iframe.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top-500px;">
    <iframe src="blank.htm" id=ifr name="ifr">   
</iframe>
</div>
```

then have your image form submit to the iframe.

```
<form target="ifr" onsubmit="pollstatus(<?php=$id ?>)">
```

add a hidden form field to your form with an unique identifier.

then have an ajax call the status of the processing with the id every 100ms with setinterval, if processing is complete retrieve the image using ajax to get html code that displays the image as you like it with css transformations, however fancy you like it, and place that in your result div

Comment: What you can also do is place code in the iframe from the processing pagewhen the code is finished by using the parent reference.

Comment: like <script tpe="text/javascript">parent.iamdone(’<img src="processed/<?php=$imageid;?>.png">’)</script>